# How to show that the normalizer is the largest subgroup of a group in which a set is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume we have $H \trianglelefteq K\subseteq G$

We want to prove the $K \subseteq N_G(H)$

However all I have so far is:

Assume $K \subseteq G$ such that $H$ is normal in $K$. Then it must be that $kHk^{-1} \subseteq H$

If $kHk^{-1} = H$ Then trivially $k \in N_G(H)$, but I do not know what to do if that is not the case.

Comment: So you are assuming that $G$ is a group and $N$ a subgroup, but $K$ is only a subset of $G$, and that $kHk^{-1}\subset H$ for all $k\in K$? Is that right?

Comment: @ArnaudD. $K$ is also a  subgroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K$, for $k \in K$, you have that $kHk^{-1} \subseteq H$ and $k^{-1}Hk \subseteq H$. So

$$H = (kk^{-1})H(kk^{-1}) = k(k^{-1}Hk)k^{-1} \subseteq kHk^{-1} \subseteq H.$$

This gives you that $kHk^{-1} = H$.

Answer (score 1):

You have your solution. Since $H$ is normal in $K$, every element of $K$ normalizes $H$ (as in your solution) and hence $K\subseteq N_G(H)$.